# How to write a powershell function with a scriptblock that allows automatic pipeline variable $_

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I want to write a cmdlet that invokes a call back method. When invoking the callback method, I want to be able to use the automatic variable $_. This is so that I don't have to

For example, let's say my function is an implementation similar to ForEach-Object:

(**Note** - I know I could use `ForEach-Object` to this exact same thing. I'm just presenting this as a simplified example for something else that i need to do)

```
function Invoke-MyCustomPsCmdlet {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [int[]] $input,

        [scriptblock] $callback
    )

    # Do somethign meaningful here.
    Write-Output "Cmdlet: $input"

    foreach($i in $input){
        # How to invoke the $callback so that $i will be passed on to the $_ of the callback scriptblock?
        #$i | $callback
    }

}
```

This is how i want to invoke it (with $_)

```
1,2,3,4,5 | Invoke-MyCustomPsCmdlet -callback { Write-Output "Callback: $_" }
```

And my expectation is to have this output

```
Cmdlet: 1 2 3 4 5
Callback: 1
Callback: 2
Callback: 3
Callback: 4
Callback: 5
```

Comment: Just use `ForEach-Object`: `$input |ForEach-Object $callback` :)

Comment: I'm just trying to find out how $_ is used in a cmdlet i'm implementing that is very similar to ForEach-Object

Comment: the variable `$Input` is a _reserved automatic variable_. you should NEVER set it or write to it unless you are totally certain you need to do so. try using something that is not an automatic variable ... [*grin*]